# How to use the downloaded support library?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have downloaded **Android support library 23.2.1**. I want to use only it's **design support** because I already had the rest. But the design folder contains only a **jar file**, 2 folders **res** and **res-public** and a **AndroidManifest.xml**. How can I use them in my project in **Android Studio**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to update your Android Support Repo in your SDK Manager, and then add the design library as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

If you would like to add downloaded .jar files, you can do it like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This will include all .jar files from your project's libs directory.